# Why was an answer that attributed original authors deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, plagiarism, attribution

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290644/5175709) ([image for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VjLQ.png)) was deleted even though the writer of the answer copied and pasted original content to avoid the answer being marked as link only.

I thought we are to flag (because links could die) [this other answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362692/5175709) which is mainly a link only answer.

Comment: The deleted answer doesn't provide attribution. There's a *big* difference between putting something in quote format and saying "The is a quote from [link] by Jane Doe" and just saying "Read more [here], [here]". The first is providing attribution for what is clearly not your own work. The second, which is what was done in the deleted answer, is plagiarism, because you are implicitly claiming the work is your own. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for more detail as to what the minimum requirements are.

Comment: I see the difference. But giving the benefit of the doubt, the author of that post, may have thought that just linking is fine. I honestly after 5 years of being on this site didn't know of link vs. attribution difference. The answer and community could have benefit more if the answer was just edited and if this was a repeated then yeah definitely then just delete the answer. Even in the world of journalism you referencing the original source is enough. I'm pretty sure this author thought he was doing that. I mean any one opening the link would know.

Comment: A moderator will need to say if it was repeated (the user is deleted, so it's impossible to look for even non-deleted posts by that user). It rapidly becomes a significant undertaking to determine the copyright and licensing requirements for what was copied in that answer. It's really not the responsibility of anyone other than the OP to make those determinations and comply with the referencing requirements. Most of the time with plagiarized content there aren't convenient links which indicate where the OP *probably* got the content from, so any source others might find is just a guess.

Comment: The onus is on you, as the author, to comply with our referencing/attribution guidelines. If you don't, then the answer will be deleted by moderators. The information is made readily available, and it's not something of our own invention. It is standard practice in academia, journalism, and everywhere else where ethical standards and copyright law are adhered to. We simply don't have any sympathy for people claiming to not know. Regarding the user account, no one knows anymore who it was because the answer was *dissociated* from the posting account. This was done to remove ill-gotten rep.

Comment: @CodyGray "It is standard practice in academia, journalism" Precisely my point. We're neither. Given the number of rules that this site has and that the user did link them at the end. I think deleting an answer is harsh. Though users can make an edit and have the answer undeleted.

Comment: Let me rephrase: it is standard practice *everywhere*. We do do a lot of things differently here, but attribution is not one of them. As I mentioned below, links are not attribution. The links did not even mention the author's name, which is a minimum bar. Yes, the user can potentially edit their answer to comply with our requirements and then have it undeleted. But, as I said in a comment immediately above, the onus is on the author, not on moderators. Deleting an answer for failure to comply with attribution requirements is not harsh. It's the least we can do.

Answer (score 8):

[The deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362652/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-used-for-when-developing-iphone-applications/56290644#56290644) provides **no attribution *whatsoever***. It amounted to plagiarism (the wholesale copying of content by others, claiming it as one's own, without providing any attribution), which is why it was deleted.

For more information on our referencing/attribution guidelines, see [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

[The other answer you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362692) is indeed problematic and definitely needs some improvement, but it is *probably* [not a good candidate for a "not an answer" flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), since the first sentence of the answer does provide an answer to the question.

Neither of these answers are a good example of [how to answer questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If a user is providing original links then it's unfair to say "no attribution whatsover". Providing a link does provide _some_ level of attribution. I can only admit that it's not enough. Moderation can be harsh and end up in deletion or it can be constructive and end up edits or commenting. Similar to how we want to be welcoming to new members I think this area also needs improvement. The goal of proper attribution is noble. The execution is not friendly to new users...

Comment: A link is not attribution. Copying others' work is not friendly to *anyone*.

Comment: @Honey - copying part of an answer is fine, if you cite and quote the author, but as an answer author you better be prepared to add something other than that quote.  Otherwise just flag as a duplicate.  Raise the bar we want something else rather then copy and paste answers, Yahoo Answers, are great for that shovelware.